# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton could not be instantiated (using custom style)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

**This is not fixed by simply changing Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**

I am attempting to use a custom button style but am receiving the following error:

The following classes could not be instantiated:

`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`

**This is not fixed by simply changing Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**

I am using a custom style, so this has in all likelihood has nothing to do with that.

Here is my current code:

**Styles.XML**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="RaisedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">

    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorButton</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorButtonText</item>


</style>
```

In **activity_patient_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/ask_a_question"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:theme="@style/RaisedButton"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
```

Things I've tried:

Changing Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar,

Clear Cache and Restart

Changing my Gradle Version to `28.0.0-alpha1`

Changing from `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` to `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored`

Checking that I am extending `AppCompatActivity`
(I am)

Please note that It does run on my phone, but will not render in android studio. I am unaware if this is just a problem with the renderer, and if so, can the problem be solved?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `backgroundTint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
<item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorButton</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorButton</item>
```

and be carefull, it requires API level 21!

Comment: A surprisingly simple solution to a problem that plagued me for hours. Thanks!